# What we call the keys next to the db0 in redis

Tags: redis

What we call the keys next to the db0 in redis

I would like to know the names i asked in the image given below

[image: image here]

Answer (score 1):

The Orange highlight is a Redis (logical) database.
The Green highlight is a Redis key of the type Hash.
The Blue highlight is a field and its respective value inside that Hash.